# hibernate-validator @email length greater then 64 characters

Tags: email, hibernate-validator, string-length

I used hibernate-validator @Email and @Length for request validator. As this.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr4BD.png)

```
    @XmlElement
@Email(message = APIConstants.ERROR_INVALID_FIELD)
@Length(max = 128, message = APIConstants.ERROR_INVALID_FIELD)
@NotEmpty(message = APIConstants.ERROR_MISSING_FIELD)
private String email;
```

I find that if the length of email is greater then 64 characters, then it will be 
invalid. If I remove the @Email, then it can be greater then 64 characters.So I think the @Email limit the length of email to 64 characters.
I want to use @Email,but i want the length of email is limited to 128 characters.
How to do it.

Comment: Please include the code into your question as text (which is searchable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without an example of an email failing.

The local part of an email is limited to 64 characters (domain excluded). Maybe that's the limit you're having?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address:

> The format of email addresses is local-part@domain where the local part may be up to 64 characters long and the domain may have a maximum of 255 characters.

Our validator (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/AbstractEmailValidator.java) is not perfect but it's supposed to be lenient and accept all valid email addresses (and a few invalid ones too).

If you have an example of a valid email address that is not accepted, please provide it.

Comment: a@aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com would seem to be valid, as a domain name can be 255 characters long, but fails.

Comment: @GreenSaguaro no, it's not a valid domain. See the Wikipedia link I gave: `The domain name part of an email address has to conform to strict guidelines: it must match the requirements for a hostname, a list of dot-separated DNS labels, each label being limited to a length of 63 characters and consisting of...`.